# Copying data from one table to another using php mysqli fails

Tags: php, mysqli

I am making a contact form for a website and i don't want to reply immediately,so i am storing the email addresses of clients in a table and i choose when to respond to the emails and also whom to respond to.

To do that,i am using this script that i have written

```
<?php
/**
New Users:
---------------------------
CREATE TABLE `new_users` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `names` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `email_address` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

Email Outbox:
---------------------------
CREATE TABLE `outgoing_emails` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `names` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `email_address` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `email_message` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
*/

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123456","sms_enterprise");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM new_users");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$message = 'Hello _names , welcome to Axel Mining Company.Kindly visit our drilling section.';
$new_message = preg_replace ('/_names/', $row['names'],$message);

$query = "INSERT INTO outgoing_emails (names,email_address,email_message)SELECT  names,email_address,$new_message FROM new_users";

$con->query($query);

echo $new_message ."<br/>";

}

//$mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I want to personalize every email i send by using  `preg_replace()` to replace the text `_names` with a value from the database.

When i `echo` the `$new_message` variable,the replacing takes place correctly but no value is inserted to the table `outgoing_emails`.

The `$new_message` gives me this

```
Hello ben alyman , welcome to Axel Mining Company.Kindly visit our drilling section.
Hello kyle , welcome to Axel Mining Company.Kindly visit our drilling section.
```

What could be the reason for the script not inserting the data into the `outgoing_emails` table?.

Comment: Try `SELECT  names,email_address,'$new_message' FROM new_users";`

Comment: Plus, your `VARCHAR(50)` to insert is too small. `Hello ben alyman , welcome to Axel Mining Company.Kindly visit our drilling section.` is 85 characters long. That combined makes it fail. Increase it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$new_message` needs to be quoted.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO outgoing_emails (names,email_address,email_message)  
SELECT names,email_address,'".$new_message."' FROM new_users";
```

and increase your column lengths. You're presently using `50` when the character count is 80+ for the message that is to be inserted.

You should also be careful when inserting and to avoid characters such as `'` and `\`, as SQL will start complaining, so you will need to escape the data being inserted.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) instead. They're easier to work with and they're safer to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( column1 )
SELECT  col1
FROM    table2
```

This works for:

```
Oracle  
MS SQL Server  
MySQL  
Postgres  
SQLite v3  
TeraData  
DB2  
SyBase
```

As seen in the first google hit I got.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO outgoing_emails(names, email_address, email_message)
SELECT new_users.names, new_users.email_address, "$new_message"
FROM new_users'
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy column1 from table1 to column1 table2, code works fine:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table2 (column1) SELECT column1 FROM table1";  
(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
```